# Adding products showing out of stock magento 2.0.7 version

Tags: magento, product, inventory, catalog

I added products in Magento and configured them properly like their quantity, .price etc but on frontend, products are showing out of stock. I set their quantity 50, price accordingly and mark them as in stock but they are showing out of stock on the frontend.

Can anyone suggest me what i am missing?

Comment: Be sure to flush all of your caches.

Comment: I disabled all cache type but still i flush magento cache after making changes.

Comment: Any other idea to show products.

Comment: This is a version problem. Please Upgrade your Magento 2.0 to 2.1

Comment: I figured out issue. By re-indexing command, the is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I faced same issue and re-indexing solved my problem. Used following command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried every other possible option, there might be an issue due to out of stock setting. You can check for it in the admin configuration.
Go to admin panel

```
stores->configuration
->catalog->inventory
->Productstockoptions
->outofstockthreshold->set this value as 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. By re-indexing, the issue fixed.